# Validate 2 fields according to selected radio button in PHP OOP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've created a question form in my e-commerce website to add product to cart.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

You can see these two screenshots above. If the user clicks on the `Daily` radio button then two `div`'s are hidden, because on `daily` option the user don't need to give an answer to those two questions. But if the user clicks on `Weekly or Monthly` radio button, then those two `div`'s are appearing. I am hiding and showing these two div's with jQuery `hide()` and `show()`. So, I am validating it all but I wanna validate this properly that if user click on `Daily` button so that the two hidden `div`s should not validate as required in back-end but if user click on `Weekly or monthly` then the two `div`s should validate as required. I am unable to get logic how this can be implemented.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="select_package_validity">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" name="plan_name_selector" value="Daily">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" name="plan_name_selector" value="Weekly">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" name="plan_name_selector" value="Monthly">
        <input type="hidden" name="plan_name" class="selected_plan_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="select_days">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days" name="plan_days_selector" value="5">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days"name="plan_days_selector" value="6">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days" name="plan_days_selector" value="7">
        <input type="hidden" name="plan_days" class="selected_plan_days" />
    </div>
    <div class="days_names">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Monday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Tuesday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Wednesday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Thursday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Friday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Saturday">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="day_name_selector" value="Sunday">
        <input type="hidden" class="selected_days_names" name="days_names" />
    </div>
    <div class="food_time">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="food_time_selector" value="Breakfast">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="food_time_selector" value="Lunch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="food_time_selector" value="Dinner">
        <input type="hidden" name="calculated_order_price" id="calculatedFinalPrice" />
        <input type="hidden" class="selected_food_time" name="food_time" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Function Code:

```
public function addToCartOrderPackage($data, $proId){

    // Note: $plan_days and $days_names are that 2 div's which i am hiding and showing and wanna validate only on if these are showing 

    $pro_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $proId);
    $plan_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['plan_name']);
    $plan_days = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['plan_days']);
    $days_names = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['days_names']);
    $calOrderPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['calculated_order_price']);
    $food_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['food_time']);
    $starts_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['starts_from']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pro_id = '$pro_id' AND pro_type = 'Plan'";
    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $pro_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $value['pro_name']);
    $pro_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $value['pro_desc']);

    $withLogin = $this->withLoginAddToCart($pro_id, $pro_name, $calOrderPrice, $pro_desc, $plan_name, $plan_days, $days_names, $food_time, $starts_from);
    return $withLogin;
}

public function withLoginAddToCart($pro_id, $pro_name, $calOrderPrice, $pro_desc, $plan_name, $plan_days, $days_names, $food_time, $starts_from){
    $userid = Session::get("user_id");
    $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $userid);
    $arraynames = explode(",", $days_names);
    $countdays = count($arraynames);

    // Note: $plan_days and $days_names are that 2 div's which i am hiding and showing and wanna validate only on if these are showing 

    if($plan_name == "" || $plan_days == "" || $days_names == "" || $calOrderPrice == "" || $food_time == ""){
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>All fields are required. Please fill all fields.</div>";
        return $msg;
    } else {
        if($plan_days == '5' && $countdays != 5){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select 5 days names.</div>";
            return $msg;
        } elseif($plan_days == '6' && $countdays != 6){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select 6 days names.</div>";
            return $msg;
        } elseif($plan_days == '7' && $countdays != 7){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select 7 days names.</div>";
            return $msg;
        } else {
            $queryO = "INSERT INTO plan_cart(user_id, pro_id, pro_name, pro_desc, pro_price, plan_name, plan_days, days_names, food_time, starts_from, pro_type) "
                    . "VALUES('$user_id', '$pro_id', '$pro_name', '$pro_desc', '$calOrderPrice', '$plan_name', '$plan_days', '$days_names', '$food_time', '$starts_from', 'Plan')";
            $resultO = $this->db->insert($queryO);
            if($resultO != false){
                header("location: plan-cart.php");
            } else {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something's went wrong, Please try again.</div>";
                return $msg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure brother. I will, but someone told me that mysqli_real_escape_string() function can escape SQL injection and i am using this?

Comment: Don't listen to them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439

Comment: Thanks brother. I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a jquery question and the answer could be quite simple I think. You know that the divs are hiding when the user has chosen the daily delivery, so in you server codey our validation could be

```
if($plan_name == "" || (($plan_days == "" || $days_names == "")&&$plan_name!='Daily') || $calOrderPrice == "" || $food_time == "")
```

or something along this lines.

Comment: I've posted an answer of my question of what I've tried. Please check my answer in answers list. if that is okay or not and do let me know

Comment: Your answer also works I would think, but it's a bit more code :-)

Comment: Your code works. But brother. You minus my reputation I've made with effort. It's ok. Your code works great and implemented your way of code to do this and removed mine. Thanks a lot

Comment: The minus did not come from me. I can understand why someone would think the question is not very useful, but I do not agree. It is a very common struggle to have your client code and server code work together nicely.

Comment: Ohh i am sorry brother. I thought it's you. But your code worked and i have implemented. It's really great way.